# Windows 10 fresh install is extremely slow

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, ssd, performance

I was trying to upgrade an HP 15-F009WM notebook that was running slowly, and now it became twice slowly.

It had a WD 320GB SATA HDD and 4GB RAM. After replacing the HDD with a Kingston 120GB SSD and adding a Kingston 4GB SODIMM RAM card.

I thought it was related to the OS so I have installed Windows 10 twice (from different media drives), always using MediaCat bootable tool.

I also tried to update Windows 10 with Window Update but it did nothing. It is so slow that whenever you use the touch pad the response is delayed a few seconds and is almost impossible to follow the pointer or even writting.

#### What I tried

- Replacing the SODIMM cards between each other or using one or another
- Reinstalling Windows 10
- Updating Windows 10
- Updating BIOS drivers

I have tried running some tests in the SSD HDD and in the memory using MediaCat MiniWindow, where I did not see any of the "lags".  None of the tests showed any troubles in the SSD HDD or in the memory.

Two things I will try after installing remaining drivers are: Installing Windows 7 instead, or replacing the SSD HDD with the old SATA.

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1580859/windows-10-fresh-install-very-slow-version-10-0-18363) but it "hasn't" any answers on it...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seemed to be the AMD Graphics card [driver](https://support.hp.com/py-es/drivers/selfservice/PC-Notebook-HP-15-f009wm-(ENERGY-STAR)/7137590/model/7174227). After install this and restart the system it became faster as needed.